# Publishing SOAP services with WSO2 API manager

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to publish a SOAP service with WSO2 API manager allowing for people to subscribe to it and monitoring the usage.

I do not find documentation on how to do this (if it is possible) it just speaks about REST services.

Is it possible and is there any docs around?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to publish both SOAP/REST web services to consumers through WSO2 API Manager.Below blog post[1] will helpful for you to have some idea on it.

[1] http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/07/consuming-soap-service-using-wso2-api.html

Note some of the content need to be upgrade according to API Manager 1.0.0 release as this post written for APIManager alpha version.For example you have to refer application access key instead api key which is refer from the above post.

Thanks;

/Lalaji